# change Text if JSON Array is empty

Tags: java, android, json

My app fetches JSON data from a server and stores them in a `CardView`.  All the data is processed correctly, but if some data isn't available at the moment the `JSONArray` is empty. The app fetches them anyway and writes 'null' into the `TextView`, while I want to have it empty. I already searched other related questions and thought it was the best way to check the length of the array, but still it puts 'null' in my `TextView`:

What I get:

```
(null - null)
```

What I want to have:

```
( - )
```

This is the structure of what is fetched:

```
[
 {
  "MatchResults": []
 }
]
```

How I tried to handle it:

```
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("MatchResults");

for(int j=0; j<jArray.length(); j++) {

    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(j);

         if(jArray != null && jArray.length() > 0){
             GetDataAdapter.setTore1(json_data.getString(TEAM1));
             GetDataAdapter.setTore2(json_data.getString(TEAM2));
         }
}
```

What do I have to change so that the `setTore1` and `setTore2` method leave the `TextView` empty?

Comment: This example of json won't enter the loop.

Comment: Why not? I cut the code of course, I hope I didn't cut anything important

Comment: Because the `MatchResults` array is empty. Or is it not the data you are working with? In that case provide an actual example.

Comment: Oh yes, of course! I didn't think about that correctly, with that hint I was able to solve it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I provided a more detailed answer if it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided probably doesn't match the provided output, as mentioned in the comment. Anyway, what you are describing can be done by simply initializing the properties in construction phase.

I am not sure of the object that contains the properties, but those should be `tore1` and `tore2`. Before iterating the json and try to set those, just initialize them to be empty strings (`""`) in this way when you don't find a valid value in the json, you will use the empty string as required.